# Tensor calculus in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus

We say that any function $f(t,x,y,z)$ is a tensor of rank {0 0} because it takes no vectors or one-forms in order to give a real number. But couldn't we have just written the same function as $f(t,x,y,z)= f({\bf r})$ where ${\bf r}$ is the position vector in Minkowski spacetime, and thus consider it as a tensor of rank {0 1} ?

Comment: First of all, f doesn't *act* on a vector. Secondly, $\vec{r}$ is only a vector in flat spacetime; it is more generally a point. Lastly, we can also conclude it is a scalar from how it transforms

Comment: I specified my question to Minkovski spacetime so that we can consider **r** as a vector. And in this case, saying that f is acting on t,x,y and z is equivalent to saying f is acting on the vector **r**, and I fail to see the difference :/

Comment: The action of a 1-form $\alpha$ on a vector $v$ is $\alpha v = \alpha_i v^i$, where each component of $\alpha$ is itself a function of $t,x,y,z$. $\alpha$ has to be linear.

Comment: Please explain more, I don't seem to get your point yet.

Comment: I think you are mistaking the affine coordinates for vectors from the tangent spaces? The coordinates are just house numbers, they don't transform, at all. Even if you flatten the space, well, even if you go to Galilean symmetry, the affine coordinates and the tangent space are not the same thing. We try to teach that in high school math, and even I remember "not getting it". It's profound, but hard to "grok" IMHO.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what do you mean by "they don't transform"?

Comment: @ZachMcDargh "acting" on a vector and "taking a vector as an argument" are the same thing.

Comment: A point is a point is a point. An affine coordinate is the house number of that point. These coordinates don't obey linear relationships, indeed, they can be completely arbitrary.

Comment: @DanielSank Yes, the language I used is somewhat unclear. Functions in general obviously need not "act" on vectors in the same way that 1-forms do, as I mentioned in my later comment.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of one-form is simply not "function of a vector". A one-form must

1. be linear
2. transform in a special way under a change of coordinates.

That is, a one form is something that looks like $\alpha=\alpha_i \textrm{d}x^i$. It has components, $\alpha_i$. If you go from coordinates $x^i$ to coordinates $y^i$, the components change, such that the one-form itself is unchanged,

$$\alpha =\alpha_j \textrm{d}x^j = \alpha_i \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} \textrm{d}y^j$$

$$\Rightarrow \alpha'_j = \alpha_i \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y^j} .$$

When this acts on a vector, you add the product of the components of the 1-form with the components of the vector, like in the standard dot-product,

$$\alpha v = \alpha_i v^i.$$

This is not generically true of how functions depend on vectors. If you have some function that depends on a vector $v$ (which as I mentioned in a comment, a function of the coordinates $f(x^i)$ is in general not), it does not have to be linear in this way. For instance, the function

$$f(x^i) = \log(x^0/x^1)$$

is not linear, has no components, and does not satisfy the transformation rule.

Comment: I agree to all what you said except that I still can't see why we can't consider f(t,x,y,z) a function of the position vector in a flat spacetime (although I agree that it need not be linear hence it need not be a tensor).

Comment: It is, but the "position vector" is not a meaningful concept in other contexts, in which we want the ideas "1-form" and "scalar" to be unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

> thus consider it as a tensor of rank {0 1} ?

In this context, $f(t,x,y,z)$ can be thought of as function on spacetime, $f(\mathcal{P})$, assigning a number to each event $\mathcal{P}$ where the coordinates of $\mathcal{P}$ are, in some coordinate system, $t,x,y,z$,

While we can write $f(\mathbf{r})$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is understood to be the 'vector' of coordinates of the particle, and get the value of the field along the world line of the particle, it must be understood that $f$ remains a function on spacetime, not of vectors.

A one-form, $\mathbf{\sigma}$, on the other hand, takes a vector argument and produces a number.  To borrow the terminology of MTW in "Gravitation", it is a *'machine with a slot that produces a real number when a vector is inserted into the slot'*.

It is not a function of coordinates or of components of vectors, but of *vectors themselves* as abstract objects.  That is, the contraction of a one-form and a vector to produce a number is logically prior to the concepts of components and coordinates.  From "Gravitation", page 55:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are, perhaps, a little confused by the fact that Minkowski space (call it $M$) looks a lot like the tangent space to $M$ at a given point $E$. (Call that tangent space $T_E$.)

Although they look a lot alike, $M$ and $T_E$ are not the same thing.  For example, $T_E$ has a distinguished point called "zero", and $M$ does not (you can, of course, always choose some point in $M$ and *call* it zero, but the choice of that point is arbitrary, whereas  in $T_E$ there is one distinguished origin.)

Your function $f$ maps $M$ to the real numbers.  A cotangent vector (at $E$) of appropriate rank maps $T_E$ to the real numbers. The domains are different, so your function cannot be a cotangent vector.

Now let $T^E$ be the set of all cotangent vectors at $E$ and let $T$ be the union of the $T^E$. A cotangent vector field maps $M$ to $T$.  Therefore your function is not a cotangent vector field either, because the codomains are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Spacetime is a manifold**

Let me provide a more pure-math perspective on your problem - maybe it'll be lifted afterwards.

Let's first have a look at what a manifold is: A manifold is a collection of points that looks, locally, like a vector space. For example, a sphere (i.e. the surface of a ball) is such an object. Our spacetime in Newtonian or relativistic mechanics is also such an object.

Now, in physics, what we usually do is we choose *coordinates*. That means we look at a patch of the manifold and identify it with our favourite vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ (we can do this, because by definition, this is how the manifold looks like in a local picture).

There is one problem here: You seem to always think about a point in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a *vector* (from the origin). While you can do this, in the case of a manifold, this is *not* how you should think of it. A point is just a point. The difference between two such points is a vector, but not the point itself, because the origin is arbitrary. You just identified your set of points with $\mathbb{R}^n$, but you could have done it very differently.

To have a very specific example: An atlas (i.e. that thing containing maps of different regions of the world) is a collection of maps and each map is an identification of some patch of the earth (which is certainly not a plane) with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Where is the origin of that plane? You can choose it wherever you like. If you have a map of Europe, you could choose it such that Belgium is in its centre or maybe Poland. The coordinate "vector" of a point will differ on which map you choose. Therefore, it's not a good idea to think of the the coordinates of the map on your page as vectors. They are just points and nothing else.

**Functions**

What's a function? Well, a function assigns to any point of the manifold a value. For example, you can consider an earth height function, which assigns to each point on this planet the height above or below sea-level.

**Vectors**

Now, what's a vector? Let's say you take a trip from, say, New York to San Francisco. While on a map, you could assign a "displacement" vector to it, this is no longer what you would think of as a "vector" on the sphere. But at any point along the way, you can ask about the velocity of your car. This will - as you surely learned in school - be a *tangent* to the sphere: it has a direction (the way you are going) and a length (proportional to your speed). This velocity vector is a true vector - it's a tangent to the manifold.

Only those things are vectors. The trouble comes about because the tangent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are also vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (well, strictly speaking they are not, but you will usually identify them as such). However, if you think about the sphere, it's clear that the tangents at any point of the sphere are something entirely different than the sphere! A vector field is just a collection of vectors for any point of the manifold. For our lovely earth, one interesting vector field denotes the wind velocity at any point of the planet.

**Tensors**

Now, a tensor of rank {0 1} in your notation is a function that for any point of the manifold takes a vector (tangent vector!) and outputs a number. For example, a tensor of rank {0 1} for the planet earth could be a calculator to output the speed of the wind in Western direction. Given the vector field of wind velocities, it outputs for any point on the planet the speed in the direction which would be denoted "west" (North and Sout Pole are a bit problematic, but I can't think of a better example right now).

**Transformations**

One last aspect very important in physics are transformations. What's that all about? Well, if you have a look at your atlas of the planet, at some point you might have a map of Russia. Since Russia is very large, one map will not be enough to cover it, so there will be several with some overlap. In order to plan a trip through Russia, you will therefore have to transform from one map to the other. This is known as a **coordinate transformation** and if your manifold is spacetime and your atlas consists of all inertial frames, the transformations are the Lorentz transformations. Such a coordinate transformations gives you a one-to-one correspondence of points on one map to points on the other map (for all points in the overlap).

Let's take two maps and denote that transformation between them by $\phi$, then a point which on one map is denoted by $x$ will have coordinates $\phi(x)$ on the new map. If you now have a look at the function, what will happen? Well, surely the value of the function (i.e. the height of a point) will not change at all, if the value was $f(x)$ before, it'll now be $f(\phi^{-1}(x))$ in the new coordinates, because if you plug in $\phi(x)$ (which is $x$ before) you'll get your old result back.

This is however not true for vectors: The new coordinate patch could be rotated or stretched - so we would have to rotate the vector in addition to changing the point! And that's exactly what is described by the transformation rules.